# How to find hyper link from multiple hyperlinks from code behind by using for loop in c#

Tags: c#-4.0

Here I am trying to find my hyperlinks. But I got the error at

```
HyperLink hl = (HyperLink)FindControl("hl" + (i + 1));
string text = hl.Text;
```

Please help me.

*MY aspx Page.*

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="hl1" runat="server" Target="_blank"></asp:HyperLink>
<asp:HyperLink ID="hl2" runat="server" Target="_blank"></asp:HyperLink>
<asp:HyperLink ID="hl3" runat="server" Target="_blank"></asp:HyperLink>
<asp:HyperLink ID="hl4" runat="server" Target="_blank"></asp:HyperLink>  
<asp:HyperLink ID="hl5" runat="server" Target="_blank"></asp:HyperLink>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MFTIb.png)

*My cs Page.*

```
hl1.Text="abcd";
hl2.Text="efgh";
hl3.Text="ijkl";
hl4.Text="mnop";
hl5.Text="qrst";

string Names="Names: ";
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    HyperLink hl = (HyperLink)FindControl("hl" + (i + 1);
    string text = hl.Text;

    Names=Names+","+text; 
}
```

Comment: Where are hyperlinks?In panel or table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first you should edit aspx like this:

```
<table id="myTable" runat="server"> 
...
<table/>
```

In the second step edit .cs like this:

```
HyperLink hl = (HyperLink)myTable.FindControl("hl" + (i + 1));
```